# Pop-up window bug

Tags: jquery

Got a trouble with closing of pop-up window. 
If you hover on ".man" objects alternatively giving time to ".pop-up" to close - everything is working just fine. 
But, if you wouldn't wait until first ".pop-up" is faded out and hover on another ".man" - the ".pop-up" from first ".man" wouldn't fade out. 
The main point is to make every single ".pop-up" fade in and fade out independently from each other.
Thanks in advance!

```
let timeout,
    id;
$(".man").mouseenter(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.pop-up-' + id).fadeIn(400);
})
$(".man").mouseleave(function() {
    id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.pop-up-' + id).fadeOut(400);
    }, 2000);
})
$(".pop-up-" + id).mouseenter(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
})
$(".pop-up-" + id).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(400);
})
```

Comment: Then do not use a global id variable.  Scope an id variable to the event handlers so they are independent per invocation.  Same thing with timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is because of your global id variable.  You should break out the fade in and fade out into a callable function that accepts the id as a param.  Then in your on hover and and exit you call the functions by name.  The id variable should be passed into the function to be used, eliminating the global variable.  Something like this.

```
function fadeIn(var id) {
    $('.pop-up-' + id).fadeIn(400);
}

$(".man").mouseenter(fadeIn(id))
```